# How to catch a Lua exception in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, lua, wndproc

I am using the an assembly named [LuaInterface](http://luaforge.net/) to run lua-code inside my C# application. During the lua execution I create some WinForms & map event handlers (lua-methods) to them.

The problem is that the `doString` (aka `runLuaCode`) method only runs the init routine and the constructors. This is fine and intended, however the `doString` function acts non blocking so the function returns while the Lua-created-Forms are still there.  This means that any exception (null-ref and alike) which is not raised during the constructor is not handled by the lua error handling an crashes all the way up to my wndProc of my Editor - which most likely kills my editor and make error handling virtually impossible.

Is there any way to create a new Thread / Process / AppDomain that handles it's own WndProc so that only this sub-task needs to handle the exceptions?

Should I block my Editor at the doString with a while loop in lua until the forms are closed?

What other options do I have?

Any advice on this matter is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Oo - woop i see... this was not intentional - sorry & thx for the hint - reminder to myself - rtfm

Comment: It is not late to fix this ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Another Lua enthusiast!! Finally! :) I am also toying with the idea to use Lua for macro scripting in my .NET apps.

I am not sure I get it. I wrote some sample code and it seems to be working ok. Simple try catch around DoString gets the LuaExceptions. DoString does block the main thread unless you explicitly create a new thread. In case of a new thread normal .NET multithreaded exception handling rules apply.

Example:

```
public const string ScriptTxt = @"
luanet.load_assembly ""System.Windows.Forms""
luanet.load_assembly ""System.Drawing""

Form = luanet.import_type ""System.Windows.Forms.Form""
Button = luanet.import_type ""System.Windows.Forms.Button""
Point = luanet.import_type ""System.Drawing.Point""
MessageBox = luanet.import_type ""System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox""
MessageBoxButtons = luanet.import_type ""System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons""

form = Form()
form.Text = ""Hello, World!""
button = Button()
button.Text = ""Click Me!""
button.Location = Point(20,20)
button.Click:Add(function()
        MessageBox:Show(""Clicked!"", """", MessageBoxButtons.OK) -- this will throw an ex
    end)   
form.Controls:Add(button)
form:ShowDialog()";

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var lua = new Lua();
                lua.DoString(ScriptTxt);
            }
            catch(LuaException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.Source == "LuaInterface")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

LuaInterface has a pretty good documentation where tricky error handling is explained.

http://penlight.luaforge.net/packages/LuaInterface/#T6

I hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for your post! I nearly forgot about the thread! Sadly I've already tried your suggestion with no success, due to the lua script failes in a .Net-Function it called. (if for example MessageBox:Show throws an exception) After much fiddeling I found out, that there is an inner exception which was not properly delegated throught the LuaInterface. After "exporting" it, I got my required information and can at least provide some code hit where my programm crashed!

Comment: It is worth checking Nua which is a .NET implementation of Lua and uses the Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR) http://nua.codeplex.com/ Iron Python and Iron Ruby are using the DLR as well. It is 100% .NET framework so you won't run into exotic marshalling errors. It is a project worth following.